# Clone git from Azure DevOps Server (on-prem) using access token

Tags: git, authentication, git-clone, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

I have an Azure DevOps Server instance installed on a Windows Server 2019 machine: https://tfs.acme.com

I'm trying to clone a repository using a personal access token. I managed to clone the repository using my NTLM login password, but not using the token (`fatal: Authentication failed`).

I enabled all possible scopes when generating the token and it works fine for all API calls I've tried.

[image: devops]

Is there any additional configuration for cloning with token? Another method that will allow me to use same password for both API and clone? (NTLM password fails on Rest API calls).

Comment: I've posted the issue also to Microsoft developers community, but I have less faith of the activity there https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/889868/cannot-clone-git-from-azure-devops-server-on-prem.html

Comment: The REST API should just work using NTLM. What are you doing to pass the credential? Vice versa, Git Clone should work using a PAT, but it requires the server to allow basic auth and the server may try to negotiate to Kerberos or NTLM when the client can perform that to be more secure.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the Git Credential Manager For Windows to revert to basic Git authentication on Windows? See the last part of this blog post: https://jessehouwing.net/configure-visual-studio-to-use-a-different-git-credential-manager-for-windows/

Comment: I'm cloning on Mac, not Windows. Will try to enable basic auth

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Linux#use-a-pat

Linux:

```bash
MY_PAT=yourPAT # replace "yourPAT" with ":PatStringFromWebUI"
B64_PAT=$(printf "%s"":$MY_PAT" | base64)
git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic ${B64_PAT}" clone https://dev.azure.com/yourOrgName/yourProjectName/_git/yourRepoName
```

Windows:

```
$MyPat = ':PatStringFromWebUI'
$UserName = ':UserNameToUseWithToken'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$UserName:$MyPat"))
git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic $B64Pat" clone https://dev.azure.com/yourOrgName/yourProjectName/_git/yourRepoName
```